How to format dates in nodejs-polars?
How can I use strftime in nodejs-polars to format dates?
Let's assume I have a nodejs-polars wrapped date:
import pl from 'nodejs-polars';

const yesterday = new Date(Date.now());
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
const startOfYesterday = pl.lit(yesterday).cast(pl.Datetime('ms'));

Then:
> startOfYesterday
2024-09-11 00:19:59.059.cast(Datetime(Milliseconds, None))


Unlike Polars for Python, nodejs-polars does not map date helpers to dt namespace on the expression object, but it goes to date namespace.
To format a date that is in the form of Polars expression Expr you can do:
// Create Expr that uses strftime in date namespace
const formattedExpr = startOfYesterday.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d");

// Runs the expression (there is no Series/DataFrame in this case
const data = pl.select(formattedExpr);

The resulting pl.select() is an object with one row and one value:
Proxy [
  shape: (1, 1)
  ┌────────────┐
  │ literal    │
  │ ---        │
  │ str        │
  ╞════════════╡
  │ 2024-09-11 │
  └────────────┘,
  {
    get: [Function: get],
    set: [Function: set],
    has: [Function: has],
    ownKeys: [Function: ownKeys],
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor: [Function: getOwnPropertyDescriptor]
  }
]

From this you can extra the formatted date from the first cell of first row:
console.log(data[0][0])

Produces:
2024-09-11

